# img tags not rendered as html in Atom Feed Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, atom-feed

```
entry.content "<img src=#{resource.image.url(:medium)} width='280', height='180'>".html_safe, :type => 'html'
```

However when I view it in Chrome the output is as follows:

```
<content type="html">&lt;img src=http://s3.amazonaws.com/agile_designer_uploads/images/790/medium.png?1356457984 width='280', height='180'&gt;</content>
```

If only the img tags would render properly all would be rosy.

Any ideas on how to get this to render properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to validate my atom feed format here: http://validator.w3.org/appc/check.cgi

Once it validated the images showed.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the html tags being escaped, you could use an image_tag and call html_safe on it.

`entry.content image_tag(resource.image.url(:medium)).html_safe, :type => 'html'`